# validación por materia en un SP de sql server

Tags: sql-server

un saludo para todos:

tengo una pequeña duda con respecto a un procedimiento almacenado el cual se supone que me debe permitir insertar una materia de acuerdo a la tabla asignatura, tengo la sentencia del SP de la siguiente manera

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[insert_asignatura_grupo]
@materias varchar (30),                             --> C.V. 1.0.1
@grupo_id int
as

BEGIN
if exists (select ps.*,asi.asignatura
from Asignaturas asi
inner join Pensum ps
on asi.id = ps.grupos_id where grupos_id = @grupo_id)
begin

insert into Pensum (materias,grupos_id) values(@materias,@grupo_id) -->fin 
del cambio 1.0.1
end

END
```

el problema que tengo es que agrega cualquier cosa y necesito que solo agregue las asignaturas de la tabla anteriormente mencionada a la tabla pensum

mi duda es, cambio el parámetro materias por el id especifico de la tabla? 
o existe alguna manera que me permita escribir la materia como parámetro tal como se ve en mi ejemplo

Comment: Lo eficiente y recomendado es que si vas a trabajar con tablas relacionadas, lo hagas mediante ids (FK); piensa que pasaría si una materia llamada Matematica cambia a Matemática (incluido el acento)

Comment: No termino de entender tu logica. Si queres comprobar si una materia existe, porque no preguntas por la materia? vos estas preguntando por el grupo (que no se que es)

Comment: si, tienes razón amigo sólo que lo hacía porque estaba experimentandp de tal manera como en el ejemplo pero mejor lo hago con id es lo más eficiente gracias

Comment: @gbianchi si, lo que estaba haciendo ahí era un error garrafal, lo corregiré de la manera que dijo Paulo

Comment: Entonces en realidad tu pregunta es un error no reproducible? porque es solo un problema de logica mal aplicada?